# Should data be saved to a file if that data can simply be calculated later?

Tags: c#, file, class, object

I am creating a program that records data for a sprinter who runs the 100 meters. To do this, I designed a class named the "Entry" class that is used to record the date the user ran the 100m and the seconds that the user ran it in. When an Entry object is created, the user enters the date and seconds, and the objects calculates some other data such as the average speed of the run and the (estimated) top speed. When the user saves the "Entry", the data is written to a file (which contains other entries from previous dates in it). My question is should just the date and seconds be written to the file and the other information (such as average/top speed) be calculated again when the data is loaded from the file? Or should I just write all the data to the file so that the information doesn't need to be calculated again?

Note: A concern I have about writing all the data to the file is that I would have to create some sort of method, likely a constructor, for setting the average/top speed in the entry object (when the data is loaded from the file). This means that someone using this object could set the average/top speed themselves, which I don't want. I want the object itself to be in charge of determining that info, nobody else.

I included some of the code for the class just in case it helps.
Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

```
    class Entry
{
    // Class fields
    private const int DISTANCE = 100;
    private const double ADDEDMPH = 3.5;
    private int _month;
    private int _day;
    private int _year;
    private double _seconds;
    private double _averageSpeed = 0;
    private double _topSpeed;

    // Constructors
    public Entry()
    { }
    public Entry(double secs)
    {
        _seconds = secs;
        validateSeconds();
        if(secondsChecked)
            calcTopAndAverageSpeed();
    }
    public Entry(int month, int day, int year)
    {
        _month = month;
        _day = day;
        _year = year;
        validateDate();
    }
    public Entry(double secs, int month, int day, int year)
    {
        _seconds = secs;
        _month = month;
        _day = day;
        _year = year;
        validateAll();
        if(secondsChecked)
            calcTopAndAverageSpeed();
    }

    // Class properties - when something is entered, it should be checked. If something is invalid, when it is accessed, it should return -1
    public double Seconds
    {
        get
        {
            if (secondsChecked == true)
                return _seconds;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        set
        {
            _seconds = value;
            validateSeconds();
            if(secondsChecked)
                calcTopAndAverageSpeed();
        }
    }
    public int Day
    {
        get
        {
            if (dayChecked == true)
                return _day;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        set
        {
            _day = value;
            validateDay();
        }
    }
    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            if (monthChecked == true)
                return _month;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        set
        {
            _month = value;
            validateMonth();
        }
    }
    public int Year
    {
        get
        {
            if (yearChecked == true)
                return _year;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        set
        {
            _year = value;
            validateYear();
        }
    }

    // Class Methods
    // Calculating methods
    void calcAverageSpeed()
    {
        _averageSpeed = (DISTANCE / _seconds);
    }
    void calcTopSpeed()
    {
        _topSpeed = ((DISTANCE / _seconds) + ADDEDMPH);
    }
    void calcTopAndAverageSpeed()
    {
        _averageSpeed = (DISTANCE / _seconds);
        _topSpeed = _averageSpeed + ADDEDMPH;    
    }
```

}

Comment: Calculation of average and max speed is trivial. You shouldn't store it in the file and just recalculate it when needed. (think of database normalization)

Comment: Consider what should happen if you discover that your method of estimating top speed turns out to be incorrect. When you load data, would you rather it a) reflects the calculation as it was at the time the entry was saved or b) uses the current (presumably) correct calculation? The answer to this question should inform you on which approach you should take.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving all that information in the database, you will need space for it. Also during insertion, you will need to calculate it so insertion will take longer (not significantly longer, but this depends on your performance goals). If you do not save it, then you will need less space but it will need to be calculated during retrieval.

Therefore, it all depends on your requirements. If you do not have any specific requirements, then I would not save it in the database because they can be computed and there is no restriction (requirement) that it should not be computed during retrieval.

Again, depends on the situation.